# Como puedo enviar los datos de una RatingBar de android studio al database de Firebase y recuperarlos en un textview

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

tengo una activity donde existe un RatingBar donde cada usuario puede calificar el contenido, no tengo idea de como hacer que la calificación que le de cada usuario a cada noticia se guarde en firebase y luego ese dato se muestre en un textview.
Por favor agradecería su ayuda muchisimo.[image: esta es la actividad que mencione anteriormente]

Esta es la activity que les mencione anteriormente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El [RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar) tiene distintos metodos para trabajar con el, uno de ellos es el mas utilizado y es el [getRating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getRating()), este metodo devuelve un valor de punto flotante de la cantidad de estrellas que se selecciono.

Puedes probarlo de la siguiente forma

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
ratingBar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
...
Toast.makeText(this,"Cant de rating: ", ratingBar.getRating(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
```

Una vez que pruebes que obtienes el valor, solo lo subes a Firebase con un simple setValue a la referencia donde lo quieras guardar.

```
mDatabaseRef.child("ratings").child("rate").setValue(ratingBar.getRating()).setOnCompleteListener...
```

Luego para recuperar el valor, solo lo recuperas con la misma clave desde Firebase y lo pones en ese ratingbar con el metodo [setRating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar#setRating(float))

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    float rating = dataSnapshot.getValue(Float.class);
    ratingBar.setRating(rating);

  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Comment: Hay que sugerir al OP que modifique sus pregunta agregando lo que ha tratado de realizar o investigado, de otra forma continuara realizando preguntas que no siguen lo definido en el [help].

Comment: Excelente ! por las dudas respondi a los requisitos de la pregunta, pero como decis Elena, la proximas seran asi, un saludo